# Issue with Jquery Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, zooming

I'm working on asp.net application, I'm using Jquery Zoom plugin on image click.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});
```

I have a Login  form in the same page and written javascript validation for that. Whenever, we get an alert box for validation, the image is zooming? Also the image is zooming when we click F5 button or reload the browser..

I'm using the jQuery plugin from:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

My issue is that the image is zooming when validation fails. Also, the image is zooming on f5 button press. I want to stop the image zoom when the validation fails.

**Edited:**
The Login Form and validations are there in the Master Page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: Can you please share URL where you implemented this?

Comment: Use $('#YourID').zoom({ on:'grab' });

Comment: same issue whether we use click or Grab..

Comment: What if you use `$('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg', on:'mouseover'});`?